# postgresql - Convert string to time

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, time

I have column where I saved the transaction time, format is HHMMSS
for example:

```
140159
013115
235900
```

then I want to convert those time to HH:MM AM/PM
so results would be:

```
2:01 PM
1:31 AM
11:59 PM
```

Here are the queries ive tried, but none of them return the results I want..

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(TRANSTIME,'hh24:mi:ss AM'),'hh12:mi:ss AM')
FROM PRODUCTSALES order by TRANSTIME desc LIMIT 100


SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP(TRANSTIME, 'HH24:MI')::TIME
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

time data type is just time - not a format. to get time with wanted format use `to_char`, eg fro your `140159`:

```
t=# select to_char('140159'::time,'HH:MI AM');
 to_char
----------
 02:01 PM
(1 row)
```

Mind I first cast as time and only then format it